# Mysql get query

Tags: php, mysql

Im not very good at mysql query thatswhy I ask here for a little help.

I use this query to select an anime tvshow

```
$getMovieCmd = "SELECT id,name,hoster,season,episode FROM topmovies.movies 
    WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' ";
```

But I dont want to show all animes with only the same name. I want only to show those anime with the same name, same season and same episode.

Example:
tvshow: Naruto /
Season: 1 and 2 /
Episode: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I only want to show naruto with season 1 and ALL hoster which has episode 1.

Picture so you see what I want to do
http://s14.directupload.net/images/130819/g6bz3ef8.jpg
(Staffel = Season)

As you see on the picture the episode is selected. Now I want to make, that all different hosters with that episode will be selected.

Hope you understand my shitty english :/

Im searching for a query like this

```
$getMovieCmd = "SELECT id,name,hoster FROM topmovies.movies 
    WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' 
    IN (SELECT season FROM topmovies.movies WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."') AS season
    IN (SELECT episode FROM topmovies.movies WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."') AS episode
    ";
```

Comment: You just need two more where conditions

Comment: use `AND` after `WHERE` - google multiple conditions sql

Comment: Well lets say, the mysql query should select the name from the tvshow. And then the query select all episodes from the season wwhich the tvshow is.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add more parameters to your query

```
$getMovieCmd = "SELECT id,name,hoster,season,episode FROM topmovies.movies 
WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' AND season = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' AND episode= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['episode'])."' ";
```

Comment: why wouldn´t it work? you use `<select name="season">` and get the season value you want and `<select name="episode">` for the episode number.

Then when an option is selected you callback jquery, pass the values from these selects and load the content using jquery.

(Form submit and pure php will work ofcourse too)

Comment: Is something like this possible? $getMovieCmd = "SELECT id,name,hoster FROM topmovies.movies 
 WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."' 
 IN (SELECT season FROM topmovies.movies WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."') AS season
 IN (SELECT episode FROM topmovies.movies WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."') AS episode
 ";

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you are looking for is:

```
$getMovieCmd = "SELECT id,name,hoster,season,episode FROM topmovies.movies 
    WHERE name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])."'  
    AND episode = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['episode'])."'
    AND season = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['season'])."'";
```

Comment: Yes something like that.. But because there are 2 selectboxes I cant do $_GET because the season and episode value is not on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
And season=$_GET['season'] and episode=$_GET['episode']
```

That is if you have them in $_GET

Comment: Yes I know but I want to do it without having the season and episode at the URL

Comment: @ArturLitau So just use the variables where the relevant data is,be it POST or GET.